# Complex Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to combine two queries into one and can't get my brain around how to nest the selects. The first query is like:

```
select SYSTEM,UPSTREAM_INTERFACE_ID,DOWNSTREAM_INTERFACE_ID 
from  SYSTEM_POLL where DEVICE_ID = '738224';
```

It returns the system name and up/down interfaces for a given device_id... pretty basic.

Where it gets complicated is I then need to look up the interface names for both the up/down interface from a separate table.

```
select * from INTERFACE_POLL where interface_id in 
(UPSTREAM_INTERFACE_ID,DOWNSTREAM_INTERFACE_ID) and SYSTEM_NAME = SYSTEM
```

Will return:

```
INTERFACE_ID * SYSTEM_NAME * POLL_DATE * INTERFACE_NAME
****************************************************************

84357177     * hillsboro.nj * 20151228 * cable-upstream  4/2/6.0

151617592    * hillsboro.nj * 20151228 * cable-downstream  8/7/6
```

How do you combine so that given a device ID the query will return the two associated INTERFACE_NAME values.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4):

To join to a single table more than once, use table aliases

```
SELECT
      sp.SYSTEM
    , sp.UPSTREAM_INTERFACE_ID
    , sp.DOWNSTREAM_INTERFACE_ID
    , i1.interface_name upstream_name
    , i2.interface_name downstream_name
FROM SYSTEM_POLL sp
      INNER JOIN interface_poll i1 ON sp.upstream_interface_id = i1.interface_id
      INNER JOIN interface_poll i2 ON sp.downstream_interface_id = i2.interface_id
;
```

Comment: And alias the columns so you know which is which. `... , i1.interface_name as UPSTREAM_INTERFACE_NAME, i2.interface_name as DOWNSTREAM_INTERFACE_NAME...`

Comment: @Shannon Severance good point, thanks, I added column aliases in the select clause

Answer (score 0):

Use a table alias.  Here is a simplified example:

```
select SYSTEM,UPSTREAM_INTERFACE_ID,DOWNSTREAM_INTERFACE_ID, i1.interface_name, i2.interface_name
from  SYSTEM_POLL, interface_poll i1, interface_poll i2
where system_poll.upstream_interface_id = i1.interface_id
and   system_poll.downstream_interface_id = i2.interface_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, that was exactly what was needed! Since there are duplicate interface_id with different system names all I needed to add was a WHERE, but the following ultimately got me the result I needed:

SELECT
      sp.SYSTEM
    , i1.interface_name upstream_name
    , i2.interface_name downstream_name
FROM SYSTEM_POLL sp
      INNER JOIN interface_poll i1 ON sp.upstream_interface_id = i1.interface_id
      INNER JOIN interface_poll i2 ON sp.downstream_interface_id = i2.interface_id
WHERE DEVICE_ID = '738224' AND sp.SYSTEM = i1.SYSTEM_NAME AND sp.SYSTEM=i2.SYSTEM_NAME;